# Can I emulate ARM NEON in an x86 C program?

Tags: android, iphone, c, arm, neon

I am developing some numerical software, whose performance, depends a lot on the numerical accuracy (i.e., floats, double etc.).
I have noticed that the ARM NEON does not fully comply with the IEEE754 floating point standard. Is there a way to emulate NEON's floating point precision, on an x86 CPU ? For example a library that emulates the NEON SIMD floating point operations.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: Note that NEON _arithmetic_ should be single-precision 754 - the "non-compliance" mostly comes from having fixed values for certain aspects where 754 specifies multiple modes (rounding, exception trapping, denormal handling, etc.) If precision is more important than speed, consider targeting VFP rather than NEON.

Comment: Didn't NEON treat denormals as zero? If so, I believe there's a setting in x86 to do the same.

Comment: Indeed, I _think_ (based on a quick poke around the ARM ARM, no guarantees) the important bits are flush-to-zero, round-to-nearest (except integer conversions) and default NaNs - since NEON is essentially a subset of IEEE-754, any fully-compliant implementation should produce the same behaviour if set up appropriately.

Comment: Are you truly depending on precision?  If so, you'll want to use VFP instead -- it's a fully conformant single/double setup.  Or are you merely after reproducibility?

Comment: I want to be able to re-produce the exact same result, as with NEON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably.

I'm less familiar with SSE, but you can force many of the SSE modes to behave like NEON.  This will depend on your compiler and available libraries, but see some [Visual Studio FP unit control functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx).  This might be good enough for your requirements.

Furthermore, you can use the [arm_neon.h](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/12/12/from-arm-neon-to-intel-mmxsse-automatic-porting-solution-tips-and-tricks) header to ensure that you are using similar intrinsics to accomplish similar things.

Finally, if you really require achieving this precision at these boundary conditions, you are going to want a good test suite to verify that you are achieving your results as intended.

Finally finally, even with pure "C" code, which typically complies with IEEE-754, and uses the VFP on ARM as other commenters have mentioned, you will get different results because floating point is a highly... irregular process, subject to the whim of optimization and order of operations. It is challenging to get results to match across different compilers, let alone hardware architectures.  For example, to get highly agreeable results on Intel with gcc it's often required to use the `-ffloat-store` flag, if you want to compare with `/fp:precise` on CL/MSVS.

In the end, you may need to accept some kind of non-zero error tolerance. Trying to get to zero may be difficult, but it would be awesome to hear your results if you get there.  It seems possible... but difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

At last, I used an android phone connected to a desktop, and certain functions were running on the phone.